# How to change the background color Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I create the one kendo grid .kendo grid use default white or off white color i want to change full background area white e to transparent.I tried many thing but not get the actual result.If any body know please respond to me.thanks[You can see image now is background color is white but i want to change transparent color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdj0t.png)

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the following styles:

```
<style>  
/* Grid header */
#grid .k-grouping-header, #grid .k-grid-header {
  background: transparent;
}

/* Grid content */
#grid.k-grid, #grid.k-grid div.k-grid-content {
  background: transparent;
}
#grid.k-grid tr.k-alt {
  background: transparent;
}  

/* Grid footer */
#grid .k-pager-wrap, #grid .k-pager-wrap .k-pager-numbers, #grid .k-pager-wrap .k-dropdown-wrap {
  background: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Working example: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/UqaPagec

Comment: I tried but header and footer still same with white  background.It is not fully effective on full kendo grid just change the row background.

Comment: @FarazSaleem I've updated my answer to include header and footer too.